# Capturing output from a background subshell in bash?

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I'm trying to run multiple subshells in a bash script and capture the stdout result to a variable. When I run the subshell in the background I would expect I can use *wait* to let the subshell complete and then use the variable the result is assigned to later in the program.... but it doesn't seem to work.

Simple example script:

```
l=$(ls) &
wait $!
echo "L=$l"
```

Then when I run it:

```
$ bash -x test2.sh 
+ wait 16821
++ ls
+ l='test1.sh test2.sh'
+ echo L=
L=
```

The output from my test program would suggest the variable *l* should be assigned the result of the subshell, but when I use echo it is empty...

If I don't background the subshell (or use wait) then it works as expected...

```
l=$(ls) 
echo "L=$l"
```

Results in:

```
$ bash -x test1.sh 
++ ls
+ l='test1.sh test2.sh'
+ echo 'L=test1.sh test2.sh'
L=test1.sh test2.sh
```

Am I missing something obvious or ... ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From bash manpage (emphasis mine):

> Command substitution, commands grouped with parentheses, and
> **asynchronous commands are invoked in a subshell** environment that is
> a duplicate of the shell environment, except that traps caught by the
> shell are re‐set  to  the values that the shell inherited from its
> parent at invocation.  Builtin commands that are invoked as part of a
> pipeline are also executed in a subshell environment.  **Changes made to the
> subshell environment cannot affect the shell's execution environment**.

So, `l=$(ls) &` would be like `(l=$(ls))` if not backgrounded.

Comment: Seems like an unfortunate interpretation of the syntax, but it seems to work how you explained it. My hack is to redirect the output for each subshell to a tmp file and collect it back into the script after the subshell(s) complete.